# Counter value to be accessible by every web call

Tags: c#, sql, wcf, web-services

I need to have a counter variable that needs to be increased every time a C# web service function is called.  I can't use the session because I dont know just yet if all the requests will come from the same source everytime.  The counter will be reset after x times, the details that it receives from the source is stored along with the details in the database.  The idea of the counter is so that the record gets picked up by "countered" processor.

The only other way I can think is to have a windows service to allocate the requests but want to reduce the amount of applications and code that needs processing.

Alternatively a sql server trigger might do the trick but still have not worked out how to identify to persist a counter value between trigger calls.

Any advice on options 1 (Web Service) or option 3 (trigger) otherwise it'll have to be the option 2(windows service).

Comment: Im am not entirely sure what you are trying to do. But if you use a `static` property, I am pretty sure that will be shared across all sessions. But you may lose the value of app pool refreshes - which you would with sessions anyway

Comment: it's not that important know webservice is written in c# in here, but knowing if it's a ASP.NET, WCF, WebAPI service matters more. Please retag accordingly

Answer (score 2):

easy way is to use your application Settings file to store and retrieve the value.

Comment: Not sure if it is a good idea to allow apps to modify their settings file.